# How to change if a drive can be used with the safely remove feature from Windows or not? [iaStorA controller]

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, drivers

I have Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and a motherboard with an Intel controller.

I got Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver installed, resulting in the iaStorA service.

I got two ports that I wish to be treated as external (hot-swappable) and thus allowed to be safely removed (function from Windows to prevent data corruption when removing drives).

The Intel controller interprets the ports I want to considered external as internal and so, aren't available to be "safely removed" within the Windows operating system.

The ports in question are enabled as hot-swappable in the BIOS. (They work as intended if I take off a drive and reinsert it. [detected without having to reboot the computer])

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: Made an extra effort to explain my intention a bit better. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It sounds like it already works as you would like.  Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want it to be ABLE to be safely removed, but it's not, because the drives are being intepreted as Internal by the Intel controller.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is disk write caching for disks recognised as "local disks" rather than what Windows recognises as "external" (such as USB disks). Have a read here (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324805) to DISABLE write caching for the disks you want to be hot-swappable. Don't do it for your permanent internal disks, though, as you'll have a performance hit for your system disk.

Comment: Although the disks won't appear under "Safely Remove Hardware", they'll be able to be safely disconnected because there'll be no cached data to be written.

Comment: @BigChris But isn't there a way to let write caching enabled and also allow to be safely removed (thus not having performance impacts [but possible data damage])?

Comment: No, write-behind caching allows the computer to put data to write into the disk's cache for it to write to disk later (slower device). If the power fails (for example disk removed)  the cache is lost - not written to disk - and corruption occurs. Disabling write-behind caching means data is written straight to disk (hence slower) but if the disk is pulled then there is no data in cache to lose.